# How to create(and write) new log file at every method execution?

Tags: java, logging, memory-leaks, slf4j

We curretnly use SLF4J for logging. So far we would have one logger per job. A job is a simple Java class that has a method execute(). Now it is requred to create a new log file at every job run.  So a new log file with current time in its name should be created and necessary info need to be logged during export() method call.

As far as I could do:

```
void export(){
    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("*current time hh:ss*");
    LOG.addHandler(new FileHandler("*current time hh:ss*.log"));
    LOG.info("something"); 
}
```

But I'm not sure if there memory leak as number of loggers is expanding.
Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 1):

Logger is designed for a limited number of loggers which live for the life of the application.

If you want a new file each job, I would just create a new FileWriter and write to it and close when finished.

BTW: Creating a new file each time will slow performance by about 20 ms in case that matters to you.

Comment: thanks. regarding performance: each job will only run twice per hour.